# Thread Priority Windows phone

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-phone-7, threadpool

I have a multithreaded queue, which i am trying to port from .net to windows phone. Now, my original queue uses the Thread.CurentThread.Priority attribute, which is not available in wp-7. How do I set Thread priority for windows phone? There is no Thread.Priority defined there.

Comment: To prioritize which work item should be scheduled first.

Comment: For that you can use a priority queue

Comment: [Thread Priorities are Evil](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/08/thread-priorities-are-evil.html)

Comment: If weak guarantees are enough thread priorities are a valid way to achieve prioritization.